# pass value from one step into the next step in ARM deployment

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I’m using ARM template deployment to create resources.

As part of the deployment (at a given step), I need to use a secret from an **existing keyvault**.

Is there a way to fetch that data at one step and pass it to the next step that needs that data?

Comment: Can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-key-vault#prepare-a-key-vault) help you? I'm not sure as I don't know which resource you're creating and I mean if you could provide more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Key Vault Secret in ARM Template by using something similar to below example:

```
"adminPassword": {
    "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<KeyVaultRG>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<KeyVaultName>"
        },
        "secretName": "vmAdminPassword"
    }
}
```